# construct google maps url with a specific zoom level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, coordinates, google-maps-markers

I am trying to construct an url of google maps with zoom level of 21. I tried this for example

```
maps.google.com?q=48.858371,2.2939341&z=21
```

but when i visit the url on browser, it does go to Eiffel Tower, Paris, France but by default shows zoom level of 17 and instead of 21

Can some one suggest correct parameters?

Thanks

Comment: ok i got it. I am happy with this `https://www.google.com/maps/place/48.858371,2.2939341/@48.858371,2.2939341,21z/` Thanks

Comment: Without the `ll=lat,lng` parameter the zoom does not take effect so you should add this parameter too: `maps.google.com?q=48.858371,2.2939341&ll=48.858371,2.2939341&z=21`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I tried both the links, the one that i posted in my previous comment and the one that you gave me. both are working fine. the zoom does take effect. `https://www.google.com/maps/place/48.858371,2.2939341/@48.858371,2.2939341,19z/‌` `maps.google.com?q=48.858371,2.2939341&ll=48.858371,2.2939341&z=19`